# Why is my virtual network interface preventing Internet after reboot?

Tags: networking, network-interface

I have a set up a virtual network interface on `enp1s0` with label `enp1s0:0`.  I use `enp1s0` for Internet with occasional VPN connection.  I use the virtual network interface IP so I can SSH into the machine even when it is connected to a VPN as I have my router directing SSH traffic to the virtual interface.  This setup works, **but when I reboot, I have no Internet until I go into Ubuntu GUI Network settings and "remove connection profile" on the virtual interface**.  When I put the virtual network interface back up, the Internet still works.  I'm experiencing this problem with both Debian on a Raspberry Pi and Ubuntu 22.04 so I'm inclined to think I'm doing something wrong.

This is my virtual network interface service..

```
[Unit]
Description=establish virtual interface to bypass vpn with ssh
After=network.target

[Service]
SyslogIdentifier=ssh.vpn.bypass
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/scripts/ssh.vpn.bypass/ssh.vpn.bypass.sh "192.168.1.113" --up

ExecStop=/scripts/ssh.vpn.bypass/ssh.vpn.bypass.sh "192.168.1.113" --down

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

This is how I set up the virtual network interface..

```
ip addr add "$ip" dev "$ethname" label "$ethname":0
ip rule add from "$ip" table 431
ip route add default via "$dgateway" dev "$ethname":0 table 431
iptables -A INPUT -i tun0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 51000 -j DROP
```

I would like to be able to boot with my virtual network interface up and still have my Internet working.

Edit..

`ip addr show` when Internet is working and virtual interface up.

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:41:6f:0c:2a:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.14/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft 83694sec preferred_lft 83694sec
    inet 192.168.1.113/32 scope global enp1s0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::8ee7:418:adc1:499c/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev enp1s0 proto dhcp metric 100 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.1.14 metric 100
```

`ip addr show` after reboot...

```
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:41:6f:0c:2a:71 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.113/32 scope global enp1s0:0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` shows no output after reboot.

Edit:

Looking at `sudo systemctl status ssh.vpn.bypass` after reboot that my script isn't getting the default gateway ip address that it tries to get with `dgateway="$(ip route | grep default | awk {'print $3'})"` which I gather is connected to `ip route` showing nothing after reboot as well.

Edit:

`nmcli connection show` after reboot shows..

```
NAME         UUID TYPE     DEVICE
enp1s0       xxxx ethernet enp1s0
router.wired xxxx ethernet --
```

If I then.. `nmcli connection up router.wired` then I get Internet back and..

```
NAME         UUID TYPE     DEVICE
router.wired xxxx ethernet enp1s0
```

**Unsatisfactory solution..**

The problem was the boot order but so far it was a guessing game and I never guessed right.  I tried a new approach and disabled my service at boot and instead used a timer unit with `OnBootSec=40` and everything worked as expected.  I would really prefer to know what dependancies I was missing to not get a working Internet connection before my service started and have `ip route show` return expected output.

Comment: Could you update your question to include the output of both `ip addr` and `ip route` when things are *not* working?

Comment: I updated my question with your requests.

Comment: `until I tear down the virtual network interface` You mean like if you stop the service you mentioned? The other IP (e.g. `192.168.1.14`) shows up "automatically" in `ip addr show`? It sounds like you are using some kind of network manager that will suppress itself from configuring an interface if it is already configured (e.g. configured with an IP by something else such as your script/service). It might help to order your service after the service of the network manager.

Comment: FWIW, `label` can't quite be considered a "virtual interface", if you are wondering something like "but I am not configuring the same interface with my script!"

Comment: "until I tear down the virtual net. interace" I mean I go in the Ubuntu GUI Network settings and into the virtual interface and select "remove connection profile", or on the RPI I had to `ifconfig eth0:0 down` if I remember correctly because I can't test it on the RPI ATM.